# Find item in list inside list

Tags: python, list

I have a list that is made out of lists of say 3 items:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
```

I need to check if a given value, say 7, exists in any of the *first* items (ie: the items `[0]`) of any of the lists in `a`. In this case the outcome is `True` since it exists in `a[2][0]`.

This is what I've come up with and I'd like to know if there's a better way to do it:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
number = 7
out = False

for item in a:
    if number == item[0]:
        out = True
```

Comment: `any(7 in i for i in a)`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan the OP wants to check only the first item in each sublist.

Comment: @OmriBarel Yes, I am not to much clear thats the reason I commented but not post an answer

Comment: Can someone correct my `any()` answer ?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `any(x[0] == 7 for x in a)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) is good as it immediately breaks when a value is found:

```
>>> any(7 == i[0] for i in a)
True
```

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Isn't python fun :)

Comment: I actually ended up using this answer, but I marked the other one as accepted because more people up-voted it. Sorry Haidro, peer pressure.

Comment: @Gabriel You really should accept the answer that helps you the most, but your choice I guess...

Comment: You're right, I should. Just changed the selected answer, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

There is a number of ways to write it more compactly:

```
7 in (x[0] for x in a)  # using a generator to avoid creating the full list of values
```

or using some standard library modules:

```
import operator
import itertools

first_elem = operator.itemgetter(0)

7 in itertools.imap(first_elem, a)
```

Comment: The generator is fine, I like it!

Comment: I am not sure, tell me you can't do: `7 == (x[0] for x in a)`, Am i correct ?

Comment: You are correct. This would compare 7 to a generator, so it is never true.